# Android: how to conditionally show floating point part in string resource?

Tags: android

Is it possible to show the floating point part in a string resource if it exists and hide it if it doesn't?

So, if this is my string resource:

```
<string name="liter">%.1f liter</string>
```

This will always show the floating point part:

```
getString(R.string.liter, 1.0)  // 1.0 liter (I need this to be "1 liter", without the .0 part)
getString(R.string.liter, 1.5)  // 1.5 liter
```

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, you can simply achieve this by typecasting. remove the template from string resources.

```
fun getLiterString(value : Float) : String
{
   if(value.toInt().toFloat() == value)
   {
       return getString(R.string.liter_d, value.toInt())
   }
   else
    {
       return getString(R.string.liter_f, value)
    }
}
```

`string.xml`

```
<string name="liter_d">%d liter</string>
<string name="liter_f">%.1f liter</string>
```

If you want to keep string resources,
You can make two templates for liter or else you have to replace ".0" from the output.

**Example** : https://pl.kotl.in/3poIS2lLJ

Comment: I'm using string resource because it handles localization also, so numbers will appear localized too

Comment: so the ".0" part will be different for other languages

Comment: at that part i will suggest you to use getLiterString function

Comment: @y.allam look at new edits you can use two templates to avoid issues in different locales

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki Have you tested your code? As comparing floats is a topic of it's own I am not sure if `value.toInt().toFloat() == value` really works as expected.

Comment: if you cast 0.1 to integer it will be 0. then 0.0==0.1 return false